# Faild to update row mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Here is the code:

```
Item.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, item, {new: true}, function(err, model){
          if(err){
              console.log('error');
          } else{
              console.log('success');
              res.redirect('/admin/filetype');
          }

      })
```

I am using those code to update a row of my table.. the id from paramiter is coming correctly and other values also..
But its consoling err as I console there but there not present any other error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Model.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      foo: req.body.bla
    },
    { new: true }
    )
    .then(data => {
     // todo somethig
    })
    .catch(err => {
     // error handle here
    })
```